# While trying to preserve json file column ordering getting error: struct type cannot accept object"

Tags: json, apache-spark

we are trying to read json file and write to a json with the same ordering on columns as per source json file. however its getting failed with the error as below

```
**error:**   TypeError: StructType can not accept object

code:

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


json_text = spark.read.text("path/to/json/file").rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])


schema = StructType([StructField("json", StringType(), True)])


df = spark.createDataFrame(json_text, schema)


parsed_df = df.select(from_json(col("json"), schema).alias("parsed_json"))


flattened_df = parsed_df.select("parsed_json.*")


flattened_df.write.json("path/to/output/json/file")
```

Any suggestion how to handle it so that we can preserve the same order of columns as per source json file